# reset index of map method javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is how I expected the result to be.

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 0
6 1
7 2
8 3
9 0
...
```

```js
let arr= [];
for(let i=1; i<20; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}
function arrFunc() {
    arr.map((e,i) => {
    let index = i;
    if(index > 3) { 
        index = 0
        
    }
index++;

console.log(e, index)
})
}
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example. In your code `arr` has never been defined

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: YOu cant 'reset' the index of a map, use a regular loop instead.

Comment: Or use a modulo (%4) depending on what you want to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) on the index to get the desired output:

```js
let arr= [];
for(let i=1; i<20; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i], i % 4);
}
```

```
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 0
6 1
7 2
8 3
9 0
10 1
11 2
12 3
13 0
14 1
15 2
16 3
17 0
18 1
19 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, you can use a modulus. Modulus 4, for the example you included.

```js
const array = Array.from({length: 20}, (_,i) => (i+1)%4)

console.log(array)
```